# How to read the msg box when "Configuration Manager Remote Control" ask for permission

Tags: vbscript, sccm

I am trying to read the permission msg box when someone tries to connect using "Configuration Manager Remote Control" to decide if we want to allow a person to connect.

Currently i am using AppActivate. But AppActivate only returns boolean.

If there anyway to get the text on the permission msg box?

Otherwise, is there a way to safely terminate the SCCM session via VBS? Here is my alternative plan:

i am able to only get the "Viewer Name" in the registry editor (Computer/HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\SMS\Client\Client Components\Remote Control\SessionState) after the server accepts the SCCM connection from the client.

I am currently unable to programmatically see who is trying to connect via VBScript.

So, my plan is to allow them to connect, then get the "Viewer Name" via the registry editor. If the "Viewer Name" is not in whitelist, then i will want to terminate the SCCM session.

Is there a safe way to close the SCCM session using VBScript?

Thank you all for your kind help!

Comment: You seem like you found a working solution but just so it is said: You are aware that with User Groups it is absolutely possible to configure SCCM remote control in a way so that from the beginning only those users you want to are able to connect to a machine? Sure if you want different users for different machines it might become a little bit complex but should still be doable

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help someone's problem.

When remote user connects, sccm will append the username to C:\Windows\CCM\Logs\CmRcService.log

Since this happens before accepting the remote user, we can use this to check against a whitelist whether the user is authorised